# Core Data NSManagedObject - ObservedObjects not updating

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a data entry view that lets the user add an image and see the preview after doing so.

The `ImagePickerView` I have returns a `UIImage` which I save to Core Data as type `Data` through the `.pngData` converter. However, after selecting the image, the view does not update to show it even though I am using `@ObservedObject` and `objectWillChange`

I can't use `@State` because the draft object is an `NSManagedObject`

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct AddItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    
    @ObservedObject var draft: Item    //Core Data entity
                        
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if (draft.image != nil) {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: draft.image!)!)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 4)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                } else {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showImagePicker = true
                    }, label: {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    })
                    .padding([.all], 20)
                }

            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
                ImagePickerView(sourceType: .photoLibrary) { image in
                    draft.objectWillChange.send()
                    draft.image = image.pngData()
                }
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `objectWillChange.send()` **after** you make your changes:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
    ImagePickerView(sourceType: .photoLibrary) { image in
        draft.image = image.pngData() // #1
        draft.objectWillChange.send() // #2
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. unfortunately this ended in the same exact behavior for me even after rearranging them